# How to remove a specific change from a past commit?

Tags: git

I made a new branch a few weeks back, and made multiple commits. I've since merged the main branch into this branch to prepare it for a pull request to main. I realized now that I accidentally made an unintentional change to a NuGet package early on in my branch's commit history. The commit that the unintential change is in includes other changes to other files I want to keep. Is there a way I can go back to that specific commit and discard that one particular change?

Answer (score 2):

Try out the interactive rebase as follows:

`git rebase --interactive '<commit-id>^'`

For example: `git rebase --interactive 'abc24de^'`

Once you have the rebase editor opened, change the `pick` to `edit` for `abc24de`.Save your changes and exit out of the editor.

Feel free to make whatever changes you wish to(edit/delete files). Then come back to the git terminal and commit your changes,

`git commit --all --amend --no-edit`

`--no-edit` because you don't want to change the commit message.

`git status` should now tell you the last few commands that were performed and suggest finishing of your changes,

Run `git rebase --continue`.

Your rebase should now be successful and you can checkout that particular commit to see if your changes were indeed done.

`git checkout abc24de`

To get out of the detached-head mode just run `git switch -` or `git checkout master`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

***<commit_id>*** is the Commit I wanted the file to conform to, and ***<path_to_file>*** is the file.

`git checkout <commit_id> <path_to_file>`

***<fixup_commit_id>*** is the Commit where the mistake was made.

`git commit -am "Reverted file change." --fixup=<fixup_commit_id>`

`git rebase --autosquash`

Comment: And that really worked? When you check out the real branch for the pull request, it looks right?

Comment: @matt From what I understand, I had that file conform to the commit before I made the accidental change, so it was no longer seen as changed and didn't appear as a change in the pull request. I don't know a whole lot about more in depth git commands, but this seemed to fix the problem